# Finding the distribution of unequal probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am trying to figure out the probability distribution for weekdays with the issue that the days have not been sampled evenly.

For a study, respondents where asked to fill a questionnaire during one weekday and one weekend. Each respondents then have filled 2 questionnaires, one during a weekday and the other during the weekend.

My guess is that the probabilities are then `1/5` for weekdays and `1/2` for weekend days. Is this right ?

Which distribution I am supposed to use to approximate the probabilities of finding one particular day ? Can I use a binomial one ? How should I take into account the different probabilities ?

If I want for example the probability of getting a Monday using the binomial dist. can I do something like this :

$$ P(1\text{ Monday }) = P(X = 1) $$

$$ = {7\choose 1} (\frac{1}5 \times \frac{1}2) ^1 (1-\frac{1}5 \times \frac{1}2)^{7-1}$$

How I am supposed to approach this problem ?

I am not sure how to deal with the unequal probabilities.

Any ideas ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Not following. Probability of what?  That a given respondent fills out a questionnaire on Monday?  But she fills out exactly one on one of the five weekdays and you assure us the distribution is uniform.  The weekends are irrelevant here.  Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Sorry if I am being unclear. What I would like to do is to compare the empirical distribution that I have with a theoretical one, to check if the days have been randomly distributed. So I am asking here what should be this theoretical distribution. What should be the expected proba of having picked for example a Monday. Is the distribution simply 1/5 and 1/2 ?

Comment: @giacomoV  Yes.  Uniform distribution ("evenly distributed" as you phrase it) gives you $\frac 15$ for weekdays and $\frac 12$ for weekends.  Given the number of respondents you can then calculate the probability of observing an outlier ($30\%$ "Mondays", say.) and see if what you observe fits within some desired confidence level.

Comment: Note:  first thing I'd check was that they really did the $50-50$ split between weekends and weekdays.  That one ought to be close to perfect.

Comment: thanks for the answer. There is something I do not understand. When i tabulate my empirical distribution over the whole week I get about $11%$ (about 1 / 9) for week days and $20%$ for weekends. To what proportion should I compare these numbers?

Comment: Right. That's what I feared.  Your underlying distribution is very far off the mark.  The kids ignored the directions and just did both on the weekends.  Kind of them to report honestly, at least.  If you want to dig deeper, you could restrict to weekdays (or weekends) and see if they were evenly distributed as to those, but you have already shown that they didn't adhere to the rules.

Comment: What would that change to restrict to weekends ? Just to clarify, could you tell what exactly are the proportion I am supposed to be comparing with if I tabulate the whole week ?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is.  we know that the distribution does not follow the rules (that's not a statistics question, that's just a fact).  Obviously the numbers you give didn't come from a uniform distribution on all seven days.  So...you could make up a distribution if you liked (or if you had some external model) but I don't think there's any natural guess.  I mean, suppose I told you I was tossing one red and one blue die ten times each...and then I said "I got 17 red results and 1 blue results".  All you know is that I didn't do what I said.

Comment: As I proposed earlier, you could ignore the original rules and just look at the weekday results.  Are they evenly distributed amongst the five possibilities?  Similarly, are the weekend results evenly distributed amongst the two possibilities?  Those questions make sense, though I am not sure they are what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just trying to understand exactly to which distribution and to which proportion I should compare this 11 % distribution of weekdays and 20 % of weekend. But I think I took too much of your time. Thanks